# SWT table with custom editors gets messed up on resizing

Tags: java, widget, swt, editor

I use a table to display 5 columns. The 3rd and 5th contain custom widgets and the 4th is an editable one. Everything looks fine on the first appearance of the window:

[image]

However if I resize the window a little bit, the widgets inside of the table get moved to the wrong places.

[image]

To make the table look right again it's enough to set the focus into it.

Here's an MCVE which reproduces this problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class TableTest
    extends ApplicationWindow
{
    private Table table;
    ArrayList<TableDescription> tableDescriptions = new ArrayList<TableTest.TableDescription>();

    public class TableDescription
    {
        private String name;
        private String type;
        public TableDescription(String name, String type)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public String getType()
        {
            return type;
        }
    }

    public TableTest()
    {
        super(null);

        // Test data
        tableDescriptions.add(new TableDescription("Rev_Id", "bigint"));
        tableDescriptions.add(new TableDescription("Entity_Name", "varchar"));
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent)
    {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        table = new Table(container, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        table.setLayout(layout);

        String[] titles = {"Column name", "Column type", "Visbility", "GUI name", "GUI type"};
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++)
        {
            final TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
            column.setText(titles[i]);
        }

        int[] columnsWidths = new int[]{100, 100, 50, 100, 95};

        for (TableDescription tableDescription : tableDescriptions)
        {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(0, tableDescription.getName());
            item.setText(1, tableDescription.getType());
            item.setText(3, tableDescription.getName().replaceAll("_", " "));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++)
        {
            table.getColumn(i).setWidth(columnsWidths[i]);
        }

        // Listener which sets the row heights. It adds editors on the
        // second event, to place them accordingly to the new cell sizes.
        // Then it removes itself.
        table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener()
        {
            boolean rowHeightSet;

            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                if (!rowHeightSet)
                {
                    rowHeightSet = true;
                    event.height = 25;
                }
                else
                {
                    addEditors(tableDescriptions);
                    table.removeListener(SWT.MeasureItem, this);
                }
            }
        });

        return container;
    }

    private void addEditors(ArrayList<TableDescription> tableDescriptions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableDescriptions.size(); i++)
        {
            TableItem item = table.getItem(i);
            TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
            Button checkButton = new Button(table, SWT.CHECK);
            checkButton.setSelection(true);
            checkButton.pack();
            editor.minimumWidth = checkButton.getSize().x;
            editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.CENTER;
            editor.setEditor(checkButton, item, 2);
            item.setData("checkButtonEditor", editor);
            editor = new TableEditor(table);
            Combo box = new Combo(table, SWT.READ_ONLY);
            box.pack();
            editor.minimumWidth = box.getSize().x;
            editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
            editor.setEditor(box, item, 4);
            item.setData("comboBoxEditor", editor);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            TableTest window = new TableTest();
            window.setBlockOnOpen(true);
            window.open();
            Display.getCurrent().dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on how that issue can be solved?

Comment: As you are resizing window, if you wan to make your cell editor to occupy Table Cell, you should also adjust combo editor bounds to new Cell bounds.

Comment: @sambireddy Well, the cells don't get resized as the window size changes. The cells together with widgets should keep their sizes, this is also the default behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heh, found the solution by accident :) I was looking at your code and thinking: "Why does he apply a `GridLayout` to the table?"

Removed it and tada! It works.

So just remove these two lines and you should be fine:

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
table.setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: Whoa, this is weird and funny. I don't know myself where did a `GridLayout` come from and wouldn't except such side effect because of it. But I'm glad you found it out!

Comment: @DanyloEsterman I wouldn't have expected that either. Oh well, at least this mystery is resolved.

Comment: We're better than Galileo Mystery :D